# Oracle: find index creation date from systables/information_schema?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata, information-schema

Using Oracle, how can I find index names and creation dates from systables/information_schema?

How can I reproduce, from systables/information_schema, the DDL that created the index, e.g., `create index indexname on tablename(column_name [, column_name....]) [local];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query [all_objects or dba_objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm) to get info on your indexes.

This should work to [get index DDL](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX','DEPT_IDX','SCOTT') from dual;
```

Answer (score 14):

Query DBA_OBJECTS or ALL_OBJECTS for the creation date:

```
select created from dba_objects where object_type = 'INDEX' and object_name='XXX';
```

More about it [here](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1102.htm#i1583352):

Comment: if the object is in your own schema, you can use `USER_OBJECTS` to workaround privileges issue.

Answer (score 1):

Building on both responses (I wanted to mark both as best answer), this gets DDL for all indices:

```
select '/*' || created || '*/' || dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX',object_name) 
from dba_objects 
where object_type = 'INDEX' 
order by created, object_name;
```